# Sql developer connection to remote postgresql

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I was trying to make connection to remote postgresql on aws and sql developer. I have created a user with name '*demo*' and a database with name '*demodatabase*' owned by *demo*.

But i am facing some issue, when making connection, choose database dropdown in sql developer isn't showing any database name.

[image]

If i don't choose any database from dropdown and test the connection, it shows an error

"*Status : Failure -Test failed: FATAL: database "dbadmin" does not exist*".

But if i create a database with the same name as user i.e demo it's getting connected successfully.

I have tested in pgadminIII also, with that it's working absolutely fine.
Could anyone please help me out.

Comment: Any luck with this? Exact same problem here ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916539/sql-developer-connection-to-remote-postgresql

The same jar driver is working fine with my SQuirreL client, so I have a work-around, but would love to get this working in SQL Developer

Comment: @fleetmack No, to get it work. I have to create a DB with the same name as user, after that it's working fine. It's not necessary to use the DB you can just create and leave it and proceed with another DB.

Comment: I actually think I just found a solution .... posting it as an answer shortly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the host name box, put the host name followed by /databasename? (include the question mark) ... so in your case:

host:  whatever.amazonaws.com/demodatabase?

You can then ignore the drop down box next to "choose database"

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work by not specifying a port in that textbox, but including it and the database name in the hostname textbox:

myserver:1234/databasename?

Comment: Not working with version 23.1.0.097, Build 097.1607.