# How to Configure and access postgres sql database with sql developer?

Tags: postgresql, oracle-sqldeveloper, database-connection

We have few databases changing to postgres database from current oracle database.
I am hoping to continue using sql developer to access postgres databases.

Please let me know configuration and further steps.
I did download and install postgres jdbc driver.

Still not able to move ahead. While adding new connection - Choose Database dropdown is blank.
Please advice or point me to someone who can help.

[image]

Comment: If you don't know what machine PostgreSQL is installed on or a valid username and password then you are going to have trouble connecting. If you do know then you need to fill those in.

Comment: SQL Developer is a propriety Oracle product intended for use on an Oracle database. While  it can connect to a Postgres database much of its functionality is inoperable. Basically, because the internals of the two are vastly different. Instead of *continue using sql developer* you would be much, much better off with a GUI/IDE for Postgres. `pgAdmin4` and `DBeaver`. (both open source) appear to be the most popular, but there others. See [best Postgres GUI](https://scalegrid.io/blog/which-is-the-best-postgresql-gui-2021-comparison/) or google "Postgresql GUI/IDE".0

Answer (score 0):

to Choose Database, **first** **you must make test connection** with valid credential and then you must click Choose Database and then you will get list of database in drop down menu.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you don't use "choose database" for postgres. Instead you do /databasename? after the hostname. See here:
[Sql developer connection to remote postgresql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51916539/sql-developer-connection-to-remote-postgresql/52994967#52994967)